# PyQt5 signal emit between two class

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am just trying to send a signal from the class A to class B but it does not work, I don't see the print.
I am certainly doing something wrong but I did know what. Here is a quick code to show you the problem, thank you.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import sys


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(B, self).__init__(parent)
        self._initSlot()

    def _initSlot(self):
        a = A()
        a.assetSelectionChanged.connect(self._doSomething)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def _doSomething(self):
        print('do something')


class A(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    assetSelectionChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(A, self).__init__(parent)
        self._initUI()

    def _initUI(self):

        self.treeWidgetAssets = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        for i in range(1, 11, 1):
            QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidgetAssets, [str(i)])

        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.treeWidgetAssets)
        self.treeWidgetAssets.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.onAssetSelectionChanged)

    def onAssetSelectionChanged(self):
        self.assetSelectionChanged.emit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dlg = A()
    dlg.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various problems with that code:

- No instance of `B` is ever created
- direct `object` subclasses don't require calling `super().__init__()`, and even if you do that you should certainly not add arbitrary arguments, as they won't be accepted, resulting in a crash
- `B` should inherit from QObject
- No new instance should be declared in `_initSlot`: there already exists one, and the one you're creating there will be immediately garbage collected because its reference is local and will be deleted immediately after `_initSlot` returns

```
class B(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(B, self).__init__(parent)
        self._initSlot()

    def _initSlot(self):
        if self.parent():
            self.parent().assetSelectionChanged.connect(self._doSomething)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def _doSomething(self):
        print('do something')


class A(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    assetSelectionChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(A, self).__init__(parent)
        self._initUI()
        self.b = B(self)

    # ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and explaination !

Answer (score 0):

As an variant. I've marked the lines that I changed for you.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class B(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(B, self).__init__(parent)
#        self._initSlot()
#    def _initSlot(self):
#        a = A()
#        a.assetSelectionChanged.connect(self._doSomething)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def _doSomething(self, text):
        print(f'do something: clicked -> {text}')


class A(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    assetSelectionChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)                       # 1. + str 

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(A, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self._initUI()
        
        self.b = B(self)                                                 # !!!
        self.assetSelectionChanged[str].connect(self.b._doSomething)     # 3. + str 

    def _initUI(self):
        self.treeWidgetAssets = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        for i in range(1, 11, 1):
            QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidgetAssets, [str(i)])

        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.treeWidgetAssets)
        self.treeWidgetAssets.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.onAssetSelectionChanged)

    def onAssetSelectionChanged(self):
        text = self.treeWidgetAssets.selectedItems()[0].text(0)
        self.assetSelectionChanged.emit(text)                            # 2. + text 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dlg = A()
    dlg.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Since there's only one overload for the signal, there's no need to specify it with `[str]`.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Emit signal with str will definitely simplify my code :)